# How can delete the index from the data?

Tags: pandas

I was trying to use the re.sub() on my data, but it keeps showing the TypeError.
(TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object).

This (example) is the data that I'm using:

[image]

I was trying to do:

```
import re
example_sub = re.sub('\n', ' ', example)
example_sub
```

I tried to resolve it by removing the index using reset_index(), but it didn't work.

What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: For `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`, check if there are null values, `df['content].isna().any()`.

Comment: or just drop the null values, `df['content].dropna(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["a\na", "b\nb", "c\nc\nc\nc\n"]})
>>> df.a.str.replace("\n", " ")
0         a a
1         b b
2    c c c c 
Name: a, dtype: object
```

For more complex substitutions, you can use a regex pattern:

```py
>>> import re
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["a\na", "b\nb", "c\nc\nc\nc\n"]})
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"\n")
>>> df.a.str.replace(pattern, " ")
0         a a
1         b b
2    c c c c 
Name: a, dtype: object
```